# Neo4J Dictionary Dense Node?

Tags: neo4j

I am building a Neo4J graph that needs to contain a controlled vocabulary (namely the Getty AAT Thesaurus). Whenever I add a new term from the thesaurus I have a relationship:

`(aat:Thesaurus)-[:LISTS]->(term:Term {term:"Something"})`

I have a read a bit about a dense node problem in neo4j and am wondering if I have 100,000 t-[:LISTS]->term if that will cause a problem as our database grows. Any idea?

Comment: In general it probably makese sense to just put that into a property or label.

Comment: Oh so something like (term:Term:AATTerm)? Just wondering if the dense node is an actual problem if I were to do it the way I was suggesting.

Comment: Another possibly similar issue is using a metamodel. For instance I was trying to model items as classes...so User-[:IS_A]->Person. If I did this, and I have a million users, there would be a million connections to Person. I realize I could do this with a label, but if there are multiple IS_A levels, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only a single `Thesaurus` node, then you can get rid of the `Thesaurus` node and the `LISTS` relationships.

Comment: There can be multiple thesauri. So if I wanted to check if a term comes from a specific thesaurus I could say (t:Thesaurus)-[:LISTS]->term. I guess I could also just store a name for the thesaurus on the term itself as Michael Hunger suggests, but this way seems to have a better structure, just wondering about performance.